# How to test REST API endpoint that returns application/x-ndjson with Spring WebTestClient

Tags: testing, spring-webflux

I attempted to test an endpoint that responds with application/x-ndjson format, encountering an issue. Upon sending the request, my application is expected to await a message from a multicast source, subsequently relaying this message to the client as the response. However, this functionality fails to materialize due to WebTestClient's inability to establish a stream connection and await multiple messages. How can I address this implementation challenge?

However, this functionality fails to materialize due to WebTestClient's inability to establish a stream connection and await multiple messages. How can I address this implementation challenge?

```
@Test
    void testSubscribeEndpoint() throws InterruptedException {
        val accessToken = accessToken();
        String body = "request_body";

        val messageString = "message_from_multicast";
        val publisher = MulticastTestUtils.outboundTestFlux(messageString, NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES);
        MulticastTestUtils.registerOutboundTestFlow(publisher, listenerConfig.getAddress(),
                listenerConfig.getPortStockAscii(), context);
        publisher.blockFirst();


        FluxExchangeResult<RealTimeFeedItem> response = webTestClient.post()
                .uri("/subscribe")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                .bodyValue(body)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .returnResult(RealTimeFeedItem.class);

        Flux<RealTimeFeedItem> eventFlux = response.getResponseBody();

        Thread.sleep(5000);


        StepVerifier.create(eventFlux)
                .expectNext(new RealTimeFeedItem().entityId("test").message("test"))
                .expectNext(new RealTimeFeedItem().entityId("test").message("test"))
                .consumeNextWith(event -> log.info("Received: {}"))
                .thenCancel()
                .verify();
    }
```

Here is the error message from the test

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNext(class RealTimeFeedItem {
    entityId: test
    timestamp: null
    message: test
})" failed (expected: onNext(class RealTimeFeedItem {
    entityId: test
    timestamp: null
    message: test
}); actual: onComplete())
```